# What is the best autogrow textarea plugin for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, textarea

There seem to be a ton of really bad autogrow textarea plugins for jQuery.  I want my autogrowing text box to be as good as Facebook's.  I want it to fit the current line only, and add a line right before it's needed.

Most of the plugins I've reviewed try to guess line height from number of characters, which seems too naive.  I've read one solution that creates a hidden div to calculate height.  That seems like the right path, but that solution wasn't in plugin form.

What's out there that does what I want and is easy to install?

Answer (score 44):

Try it. http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize
I thing here's the best. It's a very good one.

Comment: Tested and it worked for me great in IE8.

Comment: Jack Moore is one of the best developers

Comment: This one is kept up to date.

Answer (score 2):

I have a plugin that calculates just that: http://www.mostthingsweb.com/2012/01/textarea-line-count-version-1-3-released/. It uses the hidden div approach, and even matches the correct font attributes. Check it out :)

You could invoke the plugin every time a user hits a key in the textbox, and then resize the textbox accordingly. Maybe even every other key, if you want to not hog processing power.

Answer (score 0):

hey this is pure javascript

```
function sz(t) {
    dv = document.createElement("div");
    dv.style.visibility="hidden";
    dv.style.position="absolute";
    dv.style.width=t.offsetWidth;
    dv.innerHTML = t.value.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
    document.body.appendChild(dv);
    t.style.height=(dv.offsetHeight+22)+"px";
    dv.parentNode.removeChild(dv);
}
```

then you just use onkeyup="sz(this)"

Comment: Not working! text things before publish.

Comment: ^ Read things before publish. *Test